# Spectral angle mapping from reference spectra in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, image-classification, aster

I am trying to classify an ASTER image based on VNIR and SWIR reflectance of various rock types. I have standard reflection data for each rock type from the USGS spectral library and want to preform a spectral angle mapping (SAM) classification of the image based on those measurements.

Is there a way to do this in QGIS? I know the Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin can perform SAM based on an ROI polygon, but I don't think it lets you import reference spectra.

Answer (score 1):

The Semi-Automatic Classification Plugin allows data from the USGS Spectral Library to be downloaded via the "Import Signatures" tool in the "Basic Tools" tab, which are then available as training sets in the ROI manager.